# Table header from array

Tags: php

I use this code mount table header after getting some values from DB

I experience a trouble, results are VERTICAL instead  horizontal:

Where do I wrong?

EXPECTED

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

CODE

```
$query = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$data = explode(',',$query);

echo '<table>';
foreach($data as $row){
    echo '<tr>';

    $row = explode(' ',$row);
    foreach($row as $cell){
        echo '<th>';
        echo $cell;
        echo '</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Simple HTML work good

```
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I reckon the problem lies with your example here. Your $query is not as what you expected in your table build up. What you expected is probably like "processing multiple rows, taking each row in the first for loop and set <td> for each column in the inner loop".

Comment: can you show the complete out put you are getting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are creating new table row in every time in loop so write  `<tr>` ,`</tr>` outside of  loop and wtry

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <?php
         foreach($data as $row){
           $row = explode(' ',$row);
              foreach($row as $cell){
                echo "<td>{$cell}</td>";
             }
         }
      ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Just refactored your code +1 :P

Comment: You won't need `{}` around `$cell`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$query= '<TH>'.str_replace(',', '</TH><TH>', $query).'</TH>';
echo '<TABLE BORDER=1><TR>'.$query.'</TR></TABLE>';
```